# How to make a landing slider that fill all the screen perfectly for all displays?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, carousel

*I know 100vw and 100vh will fill the screen*, but I want to know how to make a good landing slider (or just a image) that **fill the height and not distorce the image**.

---

### There is a good way to do this for all resolutions?

(some example in code would help), and if is posible how to **adapt to bootstrap**.

Here some landings pages for example:
[image: 1920x1080]

[image: 1366x768 Version]

[image: Mobile Version]

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="height: 100vh;"` (100% of the viewport height) to the landing page element